# Encryption and ByteString boundary

Tags: haskell, encryption, aes

I have the following test application:

```
import Codec.Crypto.AES
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

key = B.pack "Thisismykey....."

iv = B.pack "0000000000000001"

main = do 
     let myenc = crypt' CTR key iv Encrypt (B.pack "1234567812345678") 
     print (B.unpack myenc)
```

That prints the following result:
"\250\DC4\DC4\255\223\221C\ETBx\239sF\nuZu"

If I change the cleartext "1234567812345678" into "1234567812345688"
I get "\250\DC4\DC4\255\223\221C\ETBx\239sF\nuUu"

If I change the cleartext to "1134567812345678"
I get the output "\250\ETB\DC4\255\223\221C\ETBx\239sF\nuZu"

I am now very surprised since there is clearly a predictable correlation between the input and the output that IMHO should not happen. If I change something at the front of the cleartext then only the front of the output is affected etc.. Can it be that somehow has to do with 8 or 16 Byte boundaries of byte strings and how could I fix this? Is something misguiding me here?

Independent from the CTR mode it should be noticed that AES works with 4x4 byte arrays and the question is about the encryption of a single array. AES should to my understanding perform four rounds of mixing and the change of a single byte (out of 16) should result in at least 50% of the bits  being different. Thus, it can in my opinion not be that changes at the end of a 16 byte cleartext change exactly the end of the cipher text and changes at the front change the front etc.. To my understanding the IV only comes into play as a counter when multiple 4x4 arrays are involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with haskell.

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29

Since you are using the same IV to encrypt the message twice under CTR mode it is not secure. 
Read about cryptography algorithms and try to avoid writing your own crypto code as it is more likely to have security loopholes.

The requirement of CTR mode is (key,IV) pair should be unique. 
The trivial solution would be generate a new IV for every new message you encrypt.

[explanation of CTR mode security flaw]
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/why-must-iv-key-pairs-not-be-reused-in-ctr-mode

In CTR mode F(IV+counter,key) XOR Plaintext = CIPHER .. so if nonce and key remain same then   F is same for both the plain text .. So If $C_1$ is cipher of $P_1$ and $C_2$ is cipher of $P_2$ then

```
xor($C_1$,$C_2$) = xor($P_1$,$P_2$) for same (key,IV) pair
```

Supporting code :

```
import Codec.Crypto.AES
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Bits (xor) 

key = B.pack "Thisismykey....."

iv = B.pack "1234567891012131"
p1 =  (B.pack "1234567812345678") 
p2 =  (B.pack "1234567812345688") 
x = crypt' CTR key iv Encrypt p1 
y = crypt' CTR key iv Encrypt p2 

main = do 
     print $ BS.zipWith xor x y  
     print $ BS.zipWith xor p1 p2
```

Output

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0]
```

Comment: I think you are not right. Re-using an IV in CTR makes in insecure in case the communications is eavesdropped. It does not influence the principle of non-predictablility I think. I could have used `B.empty` as IV here and IMHP my example would still be valid.

Comment: @JFritsch See the stackexchange link I have provided. Your cipher text is not predictable for unique key,IV pairs. The problem is given 1 ciphertext and its plain text you can predict the other cipher text of the second plain text when you use the same (key,IV) pair.

Comment: Not applicable IMHO. AES is using a 4x4 Matrix. Therefore everything I change in a 16 byte array/string/cleartext **must** lead to an output where at least 50% of the bits are changed. Otherwise the implementation is flawed. Disregarding any IVs.

Comment: @JFritsch, that simply isn't true, and is demonstrable by the code you've written. Mystic is absolutely correct here. You may want to try this with ECB mode to explore it further, since it's simpler and demonstrates AES more purely.

Comment: I think you might oversee that it is AES in CTR mode. According to what I know AES performs four rounds of mixing of a 4x4 byte array. The mixing is not influenced by the IV, we work only with one array here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation. See the counter mode. The key and nonce+counter is encrypted then xored with the plain text.

Comment: So whatever AES does .. F(nonce+counter,key) will remain fixed

Comment: All true, **but** IMHO it simply cannot be that in an unflawed AES implementation the change at the end of a 16B array leads to something being changed in exactly the same byte of the cipher text. This is for me a no no and cannot be explained w IVs.

Comment: @JFritsch Have you seen the CTR Mode implementation ... You haven't changed anything ... changing plain text has nothing to do with the input to block cipher .. block cipher actually encrypts nonce+counter with key and then xors with the plain text .. see the revised answer I have posted ..

Comment: As pointed by @RobNapier you should try ECB mode, but it also have certain security problems when you use same key etc..

Comment: BTW, I only suggested ECB for learning. You should never, ever use ECB in real code (except in the unusual case of encrypting large numbers of totally random blocks). ECB is totally broken for most usage.

Comment: @JFritsch, you may be interested in https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto. It is an excellent free class and goes into these topics deeply. Your understanding of how AES is implemented in CTR mode (and most modes) is incorrect. It shuffles the key, not the text. The text is XORed with the output of AES. Small changes in the key/IV/nonce create large changes in the result. Small changes in the text do not.

Comment: @JFritsch, In case you haven't read any of the links above, it's important to consider what CTR mode *is*. The whole point of it is to convert a block cipher into a stream cipher. So you're basically asking why, with the same inputs, a stream cipher is generating the same PRNG stream. The answer is because that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: +1 to Carl for getting to the real root of the misunderstanding.